# ActiveModel serializer inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

say I have this serializer

```
    class FooSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :this, :that, :the_other

      def this
        SomeThing.expensive(this)
      end

      def that
        SomeThing.expensive(that)
      end

      def the_other
        SomeThing.expensive(the_other)
      end
    end
```

Where the operations for the individual serialized values is somewhat expensive...

And then I have another serializer that whats to make use of that, but not return all of the members:

```
    class BarSerializer < FooSerializr
      attributes :the_other
    end
```

This does not work...  BarSerializer will still have this, that, and the_other...

How can I make use of inheritance but not automatically get the same attributes?  I am looking for a solution other than module mixins.

Comment: 'FooSerializr' is misspelled. Might affect inheritance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this is to make use of the magic include_xxx? methods...

```
class BarSerializer < FooSerializer
  def include_this?; false; end
  def include_that?; false; end
end
```

This will make it only serialize "the_other"

Answer (score 2):

Make the `BarSerializer` the parents class and put the method `the_other` in it. `FooSerializer` will inherits only the method and the attribute defined in `BarSerializer`.